# Timeshifting in HLS?

Tags: python, nginx, http-live-streaming

I have created the following config for hls in application 'live':

```
hls on;
hls_path /hls;
hls_fragment 5s;
hls_playlist_length 12h;
hls_fragment_naming system;
hls_continuous on;
hls_nested on;

pull rtmp://localhost:1935/live/test.stream name=test.stream live=1 static;
```

Now the index.m3u8 contains timestamp-named chunks and plays fine.
My question is - is it possible to create a timeshifted version of the index.m3u8, which would play the stream shifted back in time ?

So http://server/live/test.stream/index.m3u8 plays recorded 6 hours earlier.

I heard that i might need a python script/C that select ts.chunks 6 hours. So how would i achieve this.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use php to have an URL like this:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.php?starttime=1360000000&endtime=1370000000
```

Then you can define any start and end time to create a dynamic m3u8

Here is an example of index.php

```
<?php
$starttime = $_REQUEST["starttime"];
$endtime = $_REQUEST["endtime"];

$m3u8file = "#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=NONE\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:".substr($starttime,0,9)."\n\n";
for ($i=substr($starttime,0,9);$i<=substr($endtime,0,9);$i++){
    if (file_exists("/xxxpath/".date("YmdH",$i*10)."/".substr($i,0,9).".ts")) {
        $m3u8file .= "#EXTINF:10,\n";
        $m3u8file .= "/xxxpath/".date("YmdH",$i*10)."/".substr($i,0,9).".ts\n";
    }
}
$m3u8file .= "#EXT-X-ENDLIST\n";

header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=index.m3u8");
echo $m3u8file;
?>
```